# Proper method for detecting Apache Tomcat installation via PowerShell?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, tomcat, powershell-v5.0

What's the proper method for detecting whether an arbitrary version of Apache Tomcat is installed on a given Windows server, which we can assume to be Windows Server 2012 R2 or greater, using PowerShell 5 or greater?

Comment: I self-answered, but I'm looking to see if there's a better way.  There might not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've come up with so far is to use the `Get-Service` cmdlet, along the lines of:

```
Get-Service | where-object {$_.name -like 'Tomcat?'}
```

This will return output like:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  Tomcat8            Apache Tomcat 8.5 Tomcat8
```

And that can be stored in a variable or sent to an `if` statement to determine whether it's empty or not.

It might be worth wildcarding "Tomcat" within the filter, as this will presumably stop working with Tomcat 10, unless they decide to name it TomcatX.